# How to check if my application is secure from the common types of attack

Tags: java, api, security, open-source, owasp

I have a few applications some of which expose public endpoints.

I wanted to know if these applications are safe from some common types of attacks like(CSRF, XSS, SQL Injection).

Given the size of code these applications hold, it's almost impossible to go and check for all these possible security vulnerabilities.

I wanted to know if there is any open source library which can scan the code or check if an endpoint is safe from these attacks, or any enterprise level solution which we can configure in the CDN layer or may be on the build steps to possibly check for the vulnerabilities and warn the developer.

Most of our applications are in java and golang.

Have read about a few like ESAPI, OWASP CSRFProtector Project, OWASP CSRFGuard but they don't fulfil my requirements.

Also the kind of solution i am looking should have minimum dev work on the integration part like just adding some lib or configuring something.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Security is hard :) There is no silver bullet, and anything that claims to be is "misleading" at best. Source code scanning (SAST) is important but it can flag lots of false positives and doesnt tell you whats really vulnerable. Dynamic scanning (DAST) tools attack your endpoints - this gives you an "attackers" view. Ideally you should use both. The most popular DAST scanner is OWASP ZAP (https://www.zaproxy.org) - its open source and completely free (disclaimer, I'm the ZAP project lead;). It will not require any changes to your app but it will take some setting up and configuring to get the best out of it. Its heavily used in automation so you can use it in your dev and staging environments - theis is usually better than testing in production :)